# What is a 9th K-word™?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, language, word-property

This puzzle is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what%20is%20a%22%20word%20is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What%20is%20%22%20%22Word%22%20-missing%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.

I also want to thank a math teacher who shared this riddle when I was in a high school. This riddle is a variation.

---

For each number from 1 to 9, there exist corresponding K-words™. Here are examples and non-examples:

$$
\begin{array}{l|l|l}
    & \text{K-words™}   & \text{Not K-words™} \\ \hline
\text{1st} & \text{Japan}      & \text{Korea}        \\
\text{2nd} & \text{Yttrium}    & \text{Scandium}     \\
\text{3rd} & \text{Uncle}      & \text{Father}       \\
\text{4th} & \text{Deception}  & \text{Violence}     \\
\text{5th} & \text{Duck}       & \text{Chicken}      \\
\text{6th} & \text{Army}       & \text{Navy}         \\
\text{7th} & \text{Blackboard} & \text{Chalk}        \\
\text{8th} & \text{Arm}        & \text{Leg}         
\end{array}
$$

The objective is to give an example of a 9th K-word™.

For anyone who need it, here is a CSV version:

```
1st Japan      Korea
2nd Yttrium    Scandium
3rd Uncle      Father
4th Deception  Violence
5th Duck       Chicken
6th Army       Navy
7th Blackboard Chalk
8th Arm        Leg
```

(Though, you don't need a CSV version. A dictionary suffices.)

Subtle Hint:

> Other examples and non-examples of K-words™:
>
> ```
>      K-words       Not K-words
>  1st Solar eclipse Lunar eclipse
>  2nd Tooth         Tongue
>  3rd Samsung       Apple
>  4th Human         Alien
>  5th Error         Success
>  6th Carnivore     Herbivore
>  7th Chile         Argentina
>  8th Octagon       Circle
> ```

Moderate Hint:

> Somehow, K-words™ start with their assigned number.

Decisive Hint:

> One of the non-examples is a crucial clue.

Comment: Are the listed ones the only existing k-words ?

Comment: @melfnt No, those are just examples.

Comment: Are the listed on the right one, not K-words at all? Or they are K-words but not on the correct number?

Comment: For the record, a CSV (“Comma Separated Values”) version would, er, generally contain commas :)

Comment: @athin They are not K-words at all, and don't assign to a number.

Comment: still no idea. Is it something related to the meaning of the words or to their spelling?

Comment: @melfnt The challenge is to _work that out_. There are already three hints. Maybe they're not enough, in which case Dannyu NDos can give us some more, but it seems a bit early for that.

Comment: @melfnt Hint: Meaning, relevant. Spelling, also relevant. But in some exotic way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule of K-words™ is:

> When we translate them into Korean, their first letter [means a digit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_numerals#Cardinal_numerals).

Examples:

> [image: Examples]
>
>
>  If you want to copy & paste Korean words:
>
> ```
> 일본, 한국
> 일식, 월식
> 이트륨, 스칸듐
> 이, 혀
> 삼촌, 아버지
> 삼성, 애플
> 사기, 폭력
> 사람, 외계인
> 오리, 닭
> 오류, 성공
> 육군, 해군
> 육식, 초식
> 칠판, 분필
> 칠레, 아르헨티나
> 팔, 다리
> 팔각형, 원
> ```

Examples of 9th K-words™:

> Sphere(구), Google(구글), Cloud(구름), and infinitely more.

Some note:

> An English word can be translated into many Koreans words, so I chose the words carefully to fit them in the rule. For example, I didn't translated *Army* to *군대* or *Alien* to *이방인*. Especially, I didn't translated *Apple* to *사과* because I treated it as a proper name.